# How do I know my last Recently Watched Movies in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

In windows I go to file, and then recent files and it'll show my most recently seen movies or document. How do I do so in iTunes?

[image]

I got these many movies. One of them told me how to convert to objective-c code to use the new object literals. Which movie is the one I last saw?

Comment: You can do that with a Smart Playlist. Tell me if that suits you.

Comment: What is smart playlist? And how do I set that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a Smart Playlist:

1. Go to File > New Smart Playlist….
2. The settings should resemble this, for your case:
   [image: Smart Playlist]
3. Modify whatever settings you wish to modify and click OK.
4. The playlist will appear in the sidebar.